# Get value from td

Tags: javascript

I print results from db. I am facing problem when I want to choose value from row. I was trying to pick up the value by entering button (last column) on value, and insert that value in local storage.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr class="bg-grey">
            <th>Broj </th>
            <th>Boja </th>
            <th>Količina</th>
            <th><center><i class="icon-cart"></i></center></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php  
        while ($r=$m->fetch()) {
            $id_print = $r['id']; 
            $boja = $r['Boja'];
            $kolicina = $r['Kolicina'];
            //  var_dump($id_print);
            ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo "R - " . $id_print;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $boja;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $kolicina;?></td>
            <td><button  id= "item" value='<?php echo $id_print;?>' onclick="save()" class="ion-ios-cart-outline"></button></td>
        </tr>
        <?php  }  ?>    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am using function to get value from td. But I always get empty var.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function save() {
        var items= document.getElementById('item').innerHTML;           

        localStorage.setItem('action', items);
    }
</script>
```

I am not doing something good, If someone can tell me what to change in order to get results.

Comment: There is no `item` element in DOM

Comment: I made mistake in typing, I get in firebug empty var items

Comment: `id` values must be **unique** in the document. If you have more than one row, you'll output multiple buttons with `id="item"` and create an invalid document. `getElementById` will usually return the *first* one, but at that point you're into unspecified behavior and the browser could pick any, or none, and still be "correct." Separately, the `innerHTML` of your `button` elements is blank.

Comment: When asking a question about client-side code, show the HTML that the browser sees, not the PHP that generates HTML the browser will see.

Comment: Yes you are right, so it could not be done this way. I have many rows in table and it always print 1 value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to save the value of the button that was clicked, you don't need any `id`s at all.

The minimum-changes approach is to pass `this` into your handler as an argument, and then use the argument's `value` property in the handler's code:

```
<td><button value='<?php echo $id_print;?>' onclick="save(this)" class="ion-ios-cart-outline"></button></td>
<!-- Note ------------------------------------------------^^^^^  -->
```

then

```
function save(element) {
    localStorage.setItem('action', element.value);
}
```

You might also consider adding `type="button"` to your `button` elements, since the default `type` of `button`s is (to me, surprisingly) `type="submit"`, so if you have those buttons in a form, they'll submit the form.

Re your comment:

> That is exactly what I was looking for, but in table I have more rows and more could be selected. By doing this only one value is possible to select. Is it possible so save values in local storage by clicking on them

If you mean as an array, yes, you can do that. Here's one way:

```
function save(element) {
    var actions = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("actions") || "[]");
    if (actions.findIndex(element.value) == -1) {
        actions.push(element.value);
        localStorage.setItem("actions", JSON.stringify(actions));
    }
}
```

That maintains an array in local storage as JSON (since all local storage values are strings). The first part gets the existing array (if any) or a blank one (if none):

```
var actions = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("actions") || "[]");
```

Then we use the ES2015 (aka "ES6") function `Array#findIndex` (which can be polyfilled/shimmmed, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)) to see if the value is already in the array and, if not, we add it:

```
if (actions.findIndex(element.value) == -1) {
    actions.push(element.value);
    localStorage.setItem("actions", JSON.stringify(actions));
}
```

If for any reason you don't want to shim/polyfill `Array#findIndex`, you can use the ES5 function `Array#some` instead:

```
if (!actions.some(function(e) { return e === element.value; })) {
    actions.push(element.value);
    localStorage.setItem("actions", JSON.stringify(actions));
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, but in table I have more rows and more could be selected. By doing this only one value is possible to select. Is it possible so save values in local storage by clicking on them

Comment: @user3651819: I've added to the answer to show how to store an array of them.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is what I was looking for